# Bidirectional many-to-one assosiation. When inserting a new Child a new unwanted Parent ist also inserted with the same Name from the Child

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

My goal is to select the existing Parent from the Dropdown and create a new Child with the name in the Text Input.

When inserting a new Child a new unwanted Parent ist also inserted with the same Name as the new Child. I think my problem is in my HTML code but I've added all the relevant code to the question.

I'm using Spring MVC, Spring JPA, and Thymeleaf.

[HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORpD4.png)

After submitting I get this in the console

```
Marken name= Example Marke
Geschaeftsfeld name= Example Marke
Hibernate: insert into geschaeftsfeld (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Marke (geschaeftsfeld_id, name, id) values (?, ?)
```

as you can see the Parent name and Child name are the same. the Parent name should be the one selected in the Dropdown.

I think the mistake is in my HTML code (thymeleaf) that for some reason it sets the same name to the two attributes. If I'm Wrong I've added my Parent Class code and Child Class below.

```html
       <form action="#" th:action="@{/neuemarke}" th:object="${marke}" method="POST">                       
          <select class="form-control" th:field="${geschaeftsfeld}" id="geschaeftsfeld">
            <option value="0">select Geschaeftsfeld</option>
            <option th:each="gf : ${listAllGf}" th:value="${gf.id}" th:text="${gf.name}"></option>
          </select>
   
          <input type="text" th:field="${marke.name}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save </button>
        </form>
```

**Controller**

```java
        @GetMapping({"/einstellungenmarken"})
        public String einstellungenMarke(Model model) {
            //fügt die listen zu den Modell hinzu
            model.addAttribute("listAllGf", gfService.getAllGeschaeftsfelds());
            model.addAttribute("listAllMk", mkService.getAllMarken());
            model.addAttribute("geschaeftsfeld", new Geschaeftsfeld());
            model.addAttribute("marke", new Marke());
            //gibt den template zurück (HTML)
            return "/Einstellungen/marken";
        }

        @PostMapping("/neuemarke")
        public String neueMarke(@ModelAttribute("marke") Marke marke, 
        @ModelAttribute("geschaeftsfeld") Geschaeftsfeld geschaeftsfeld) {
            System.out.println("Marken name= " + marke.getName());
            System.out.println("Geschaeftsfeld name= " + 
            geschaeftsfeld.getName());
            marke.setGeschaeftsfeld(geschaeftsfeld);
            mkService.save(marke);
            return "redirect:/einstellungenmarken";     
        }
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake in my HTML code.

`th:field="*{geschaeftsfeld}"` instead of `th:field="${geschaeftsfeld}"`

and

`th:field="*{name}"` instead of `th:field="${marke.name}"`

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/neuemarke}" th:object="${marke}" method="POST">                      
    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{geschaeftsfeld}" id="geschaeftsfeld">
        <option value="0">select Geschaeftsfeld</option>
        <option th:each="gf : ${listAllGf}" th:value="${gf.id}" th:text="${gf.name}"></option>
    </select>                                       
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Save </button>
</form>
```